# Animation TextView visible change to invisible time

Tags: android, kotlin, animation

Hey I have 6x TextView

```
 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/text1"
    android:visibility="visible"
    />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text2"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text3"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text4"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text5"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text6"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    />
```

The first has value visible  `android:id="@+id/text1"`
everything else is invisible
How to make the next text visible and the previous invisible every 3 seconds
the last text should appear, then disappear and not restart the animation again

A programming language kotlin

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

you can use a function like the next one:

```
fun View.fadeOut(duration: Duration) {
this.clearAnimation()
this.animate()
    .setDuration(duration.time)
    .setInterpolator(AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator())
    .setListener(object : AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
        override fun onAnimationEnd(animation: Animator?) {
            super.onAnimationEnd(animation)
            //new animation
        }
    })
    .alpha(0f)
```

}

You must understand this part, is a listener:

```
    .setListener(object : AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
        override fun onAnimationEnd(animation: Animator?) {
            super.onAnimationEnd(animation)
            //new animation
        }
    })
```

So when "onAnimationEnd" you can trigger a new animation and then repeat

Comment: You can just use ``withEndAction`` instead of the listener, it's nice!